# Assign labels to input queue batch tensorflow

Tags: python, image, input, queue, tensorflow

I am reading images from jpeg files and creating my image batch. The labels{0,1} for images are in a list "labels". 
The code for reading images is

```
def image_reader():

    # filename queue
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
    tf.train.match_filenames_once(data_path + "/*.jpg"))

    # Read an entire image file which is required s
    image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

    # Read a whole file from the queue, the first returned value in   the tuple is the filename
    key, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)

    # Decode the image as a JPEG file this will give us an image tensor

    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)
    return image, key
```

The image returned from queue is tensor object. How can I resize it. tf.resize function does not work. And how can I assign labels to my image based on key. 
Key is also a tensor object and can be accessed in session but not outside it.

Comment: Is this the function you tried? https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/image.html#resize_images

Could you provide more info why tf.resize doesn't work? Any error message?

Comment: That's the one. Error message says: value error \'image'\ must be fully defined.
I cannot use set_shape function to define image shape after decode_jpeg because all my images have different shapes.

Comment: Could you find out what are various shapes with tf.shape? And apply tf.reshape with a size appropriate to each particular image and its shape?